# Need shell script to trigger .py(python script) which is in remote machine

Tags: python, shell, splunk

I'm having total 2 servers:

- **Server1** -> Splunk server(Splunk Monitoring tool)
- **Server2** -> Server that has python scripts.

In `Server1` if any alter triggers there is an option to run a script. So when alert triggers I need a shell script which can login into `Server2`(which has python code located in C:\abc\pythonscripts\xyz.py) and execute it.

I don't have any coding knowledge and I need help in getting shell query which can trigger python script which is located in different server.

Comment: At a minimum you need to say what operating systems are installed on Server1 and Server2. Can you install software on either or both of them? Do you have a security team with opinions on how this should be done?

Comment: @Ben Server1 is a linux machine and in Server2 we have windows,linux and AIX. there are multiple servers where my script need to run. just I took one server(server2) as example. What type of software installation we need??